# Vb.net WPF dispatcher delegate memory leak help

Tags: wpf, vb.net, memory-leaks, delegates, dispatcher

I am using the following code to test a problem I am trying to solve.

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 250000
            Dim d As New test_delegate(AddressOf test)
            Dispatcher.Invoke(d, " SUPER SUPER SUPERSPERSUPERSUPERvSUPERSUPERSUPERSUPERv LONG Test")
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub test_delegate(ByVal txt As String)
    Private Sub test(ByVal txt As String)
        txtTest.Text = txt
    End Sub
End Class
```

the application leaks memory slowly but noticeably.

how do I clean up (or dispose of) each delegate I am creating?
since there is no d.dispose?

thanks!

Comment: I ran this example, but I'm not seeing any memory leak. I do see a slight memory increase over time, but nothing that indicates that there's anything more than the overhead of creating 250k delegates.

Comment: that is true, but the 250k delegates in memory never go away... how do i make them go away after I am done with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if you declare the new delegate in the global scope and invoke as needed it fixes this problem:

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 250000
            Dispatcher.Invoke(d, " SUPER SUPER SUPERSPERSUPERSUPERvSUPERSUPERSUPERSUPERv LONG Test")
        Next
    End Sub

    Dim d As New test_delegate(AddressOf test)
    Private Delegate Sub test_delegate(ByVal txt As String)
    Private Sub test(ByVal txt As String)
        txtTest.Text = txt
    End Sub
End Class
```